# How to get rid of black edges of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to have completely white background so i'm adding following layer

```
var layer1 = cc.LayerColor.create(
  new cc.Color(255, 255, 255, 255), 1024, 768);
this.addChild(layer1,0,0);
```

and it fills the canvas but still black lines appear on the edges. Depending on size of the window those appear be on the top or sides. It happens in chrome, and as i managed to find out it utilities webgl context with following settings.
Also if i don't add any child it's all black.

```
 {      'stencil': true,
        'preserveDrawingBuffer': true,
        'antialias': false,
        'alpha': false});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the resolution and policy setting in `main.js`? (I'm guessing you are using v3.x)

Let's asume you are using `1024, 764, cc.ResolutonPolicy.SHOW_ALL`, your problem will surely go away if you:

1. Set the background layer's size just a bit bigger just in case (say, 1030 x 770)
2. Set the layer to be centered in the screen: `layer1.setPosition(1024/2, 764/2);`